# SQL Assign/Generate unique colours for data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, colors, unique

I have a query that returns a number of string values. I need to assign a colour to each unique value but there is no way for me to know how many unique values there will be or in what order. Here is what the query returns at the moment:

```
   |    ID    |    Value    |   Colour   | 
         1         XF452          ?
         2         ALL1F5         ?
         3         NULL           ?
         1         XF452
         2         BD4F
         3         NULL
         1         XF452
         2         XF452
         3         XF452
```

I would like to assign a colour to each different value so that it could end up looking like this:

```
   |    ID    |    Value    |   Colour   | 
         1         XF452        #880010
         2         ALL1F5       #FF0000
         3         NULL         #8C8C8C
         1         XF452        #880010
         2         BD4F         #002871
         3         NULL         #8C8C8C
         1         XF452        #880010
         2         XF452        #880010
         3         XF452        #880010
```

I semi-achieved this already by obtaining the unicode value of the Value column and appending a '#' to the beginning but the colour variation was extremely slim - mostly just different shades of the same colour. Does anybody have any better ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a sub query to get each value and assign it a colour (using whichever method you choose) using:

```
SELECT value, getMyColour() AS colour FROM table GROUP BY value;
```

You can then join this subquery to your original tables to get the values out:

```
SELECT table.id, table.value, subq.colour 
FROM table, 
    (SELECT value, getMyColour() AS colour FROM table GROUP BY value) subq
WHERE table.value = subq.value
```

Answer (score 0):

what I suggest is,

Get distinct value from your table into temp table.

```
create table #temp(value varchar(10),color_code varchar(100))

insert into #temp
select distinct value,getcolor from yourtable
```

Now you just need to join the tables like this

```
update u SET Color=t.color_code from yourtable u join #temp t
on u.value=t.value
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do it is by using NEWID().  Here is an example that assigns random 4-byte values to the tables in information_schema.columns:

```
select max(cast(NEWID() as BINARY(4))) over (partition by table_name), table_name
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

The `cast(NEWID() as BINARY(4))` expression produces a random 4-byte value.  The `max() over (partition . . .)`  assigns the same value to everything with the same table_name (in this case).  You would use the following expression:

```
select max(cast(NEWID() as BINARY(4))) over (partition by value)
```

By the way, if you wanted graduated colors rather than random colors, I would consider something like:

```
select cast((dense_rank(value) over (partition by value))/(select count(distinct value)*1.0 from table)*power(2.0, 32) as binary(4))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SET [Color] =  '#' +  CONVERT(VARCHAR(max), CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(3), 2)
```